# Word/phrase to describe time of an event relative to a second event

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, phrase-requests

I'm reviewing papers that discuss the relationship between exercise and cognitive testing. Specifically, I'm categorizing papers by when the exercise happened relative to the cognitive test.

For example, category 1 might be papers where the exercise and cognitive testing happened concurrently, category 2 contains papers where testing happened immediately after cessation of exercise. There are about 5 categories, each one covers a different amount of time between exercise and testing (1 hour, 1 week, 1 year etc).

What word, or short phrase, can I use to describe this type of temporal breakdown? I'd like to be able to use the word/phrase in a sentence like:

- *"Does the relationship between exercise and cognitive testing differ depending on < word >?"*

A few words that I've considered but don't quite fit the bill:

- Recency: doesn't really capture the case where exercise and testing are happening at the same time
- Timescale: to me, this seems to imply something about duration rather than when the event occurred relative to another

Comment: Have you considered “chronology”?

Comment: "...the delay before testing" or "...the duration between the exercise and the test" or "...the intermediate duration" or "...the temporal spacing of the exercise and test" are all options.

Comment: Order, sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for *recency* (how recently it happened) so:

"Does the recency of exercise influence the results of cognitive testing?"

See *recency* on [ODOL](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recency):

> Research has also shown, however, that self-reported drug use increases as recency decreases.
>
> We then computed a recency of use measure by subtracting the difference between the respondent's actual age and the age he or she last reported any use of a particular substance.

Answer (score 0):

Interval. Overlap. Their Temporal relation (or connection).